# Differentiating and equation that contains an unknown $y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I am given the following in order to expand a taylor series:

$$y''=3+x-y^2$$
$$y(0)=1$$
$$y'(0)= -2$$

What would the result of differentiating the first function be? 
I am not sure what to do with the $y$?

Does it become, $$y'''= 1 + (y')^2$$
Or would we be using partial differentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$y'''=1-2yy'$$ by the chain rule.

Comment: So if I put $f(x,y) = 3 + x - y^2$ I do this:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $$
Which then gives me: $1 - 2yy'$

Comment: What about if I differentiate further, how would I differentiate $ y''' = 1 - 2yy'$?

Comment: It is $$y^{(iv)}=-2y'^2-2yy''$$